# How to make a print, only excute once

Tags: python

I am trying to make a code where saying a word will show a list but I want the first print to only print once and then display the rest of the list. However, the first print, displays after every item added any idea on how to make it so there's a counter to the first print? any help is appreciated thank you.

```
if response == "done":
    count = 0
    while count < len(todos):
        print("**Treasure entry complete! Here is the treasure**"),
        print("-",todos[count])
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: is that solution .u want! or please place expected output so that v can solve ur problem

Comment: You destroyed the question by removing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if response == "done":
    count = 0
    print("**Treasure entry complete! Here is the treasure**"),
    while count < len(todos):

        print("-",todos[count])
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't have figured this out sooner!